# What is '1' testing against in 'if !1 | finish' in a vimscript?

Tags: vim

I've seen the following line commonly used in other people's vimrc files:

```
if !1 | finish | endif
```

I get that it's saying if not '1', then fishing sourcing the file, but I can't find any documentation of what '1' is. I've tried every way I can think of to search the vim user manual for references to '1', but haven't turned up anything.

My closest guess is that it's testing if evaluations can occur, which may not be possible in minimal versions. If that's the case, then this capability probably bound to a specific feature listed in `:h +feature-list`, but I'm not sure which it is.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `1` is just the number, and (like any other non-zero number) stands for a *true* boolean value. So this checks whether expressions can be evaluated (as this depends on the `+eval` feature that can be excluded from builds, though it predominantly isn't).

`:help no-eval-feature` has more information on this topic, and it suggests that the negated test doesn't work, as

> the argument of the ":if" and everything between the ":if" and the matching ":endif" is ignored.

I don't know where you saw that, but it may be a form of [Cargo cult](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult).